# How can I daemonize a grunt watch command using a launchd .plist file?

Tags: macos, gruntjs, launchd, grunt-contrib-watch, launch-agent

I am trying to run `grunt watch` when my user logs into my OS X machine, so that I don't have to run `grunt watch` in my $APP_ROOT dir manually every time.

I have the following `org.grunt.watch.plist` file within `/Library/LaunchAgents`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>

    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.grunt.watch</string>

    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>

     <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/bin/grunt-watch-launchd</string>
    </array>

  </dict>
</plist>
```

`/usr/local/bin/grunt-watch-launchd` is a shell script I created:

```
#!/bin/sh

APP_ROOT=/path/to/htdocs/app
/usr/local/bin/daemon -- /usr/local/bin/grunt watch --gruntfile="$APP_ROOT"/Gruntfile.js > /tmp/grunt-watch-launchd.log 2>&1
```

The script should use the `daemon` utility (installed with `brew install daemon`) and "daemonize" the `grunt watch` command which in turn loads a `Gruntfile.js` configuration and starts the watch task.

When I manually run `/usr/local/bin/grunt-watch-launchd` from the CLI with my user, everything works great. I see a `daemon` with `ps aux | grep grunt` which runs the `grunt watch` command. If I then edit a file inside `APP_ROOT`, Grunt's `watch` task triggers the specific tasks inside my `Gruntfile.js`.

But the point is that I would like that `launchd` automatically starts `/usr/local/bin/grunt-watch-launchd` when I log in with my user. The problem is that when I run `launchctl`:

`launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/org.grunt.watch.plist`

The service is not loaded. Or at least, `launchd` calls the script (because I see that the file `/tmp/grunt-watch-launchd.log` is created so the script runs, though `/tmp/grunt-watch-launchd.log` is empty), but the daemon process seems not to be created or is somehow killed by `launchd`.

Also, nothing appears inside `/var/log/system.log`. If I try to run `launchctl` with sudo:

`sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/org.grunt.watch.plist && sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/org.grunt.watch.plist`

`/tmp/grunt-watch-launchd.log` will contain the following line:

```
daemon: fatal: refusing to execute unsafe program: /usr/local/bin/grunt (/usr/local/lib is group writable)
```

Using sudo, `/var/log/system.log` tells me:

```
Jun 11 18:22:24 antons-mbp com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.grunt.watch[83009]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
```

In either ways (`launchctl` with and without sudo), I can confirm that the service is not started:

```
mymachine:~ user$ launchctl list | grep grunt
-   0   org.grunt.watch
```

What's wrong and what's the correct way to run this script as a daemon when my user logs in?

Thanks for your attention.

EDIT:
I forgot to say that I use Mac OS X 10.12 Sierra, installed Grunt with `npm` and I am using a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) (if that may help).

EDIT 2:
I found the issue. When running as a `launchd` agent, the script was not able to find a command because the user of the agent wasn't my user. Therefore a 127 error occurred.

So this is for all the guys like me that stuck on a really simple `launchd` agent:

- Always check that the commands you use are in the PATH of the user who launches the command. Use absolute paths, and if necessary, set the PATH variable on the first line of your script.
- Redirect all the command output to a file so that you can see if an error occurs when `launchd` launches the script (in my case the error didn't appear in `/var/log/system.log` for some reason).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with either `grunt` or the `daemon` utility, but I'm pretty sure `daemon` is conflicting with the way launchd manages jobs. Essentially, you're using two different daemon-creation tools that do things differently, and you need to pick just one.

More specifically, I suspect `daemon` is launching `grunt` in the background (i.e. daemonizing it). But launchd expects the jobs it manages to stay in the foreground where it can monitor and control them. What's probably happening is that launchd launches your script, the script runs `grunt watch` in the background and then exits... and launchd sees that the job has exited and helpfully cleans up leftover subprocesses like `grunt`. Result: no actual `grunt` daemon running.

You could add `<key>AbandonProcessGroup</key><true/>` to your .plist to tell launchd not to kill off background processes, but really it'd be better to do things the launchd way and leave `grunt` in the foreground. So either remove the `daemon` command from your script, or replace it with `exec` which'll run `grunt` as a top-level process under launchd (while running it normally would make it subprocess of the shell, and leave the shell as the top-level process under launchd).

There may be other problems here, but it'll be hard to tell until this one gets fixed.

Comment: Thanks! I found the issue, you can check my EDIT 2